# How to make Excel subtract and add (not sum nor subtotal) only the values of the cells shown after using a filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, equations

As shown in the image below, when I use the filter in column A to show only apples, the balance column shows wrong numbers because it takes into account the hidden cells which belongs to oranges.

[image: Press here to see the image]

I use simple plus and minus equation `(=D5+B6-C6)`.

Please, how to make excel subtract and add only the values of the cells shown after using a filter?

Provide an actual equation to solve this example, please.

Comment: You appear to be a new user, please read up on "Superuser" -> https://superuser.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

No direct answer, but a tip that will most likely have you go in the right direction:

`SUBTOTAL(n,reference)`
where n>100 will sum, add, count and so on the VISIBLE cells in the reference range.

Ref, for LibreOffice:
https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Documentation/Calc_Functions/SUBTOTAL
*... should be very equal to what Excel has.*

Answer (score 0):

```
D3: =SUBTOTAL(9,$B$3:B3)-SUBTOTAL(9,$C$3:C3)
```

and fill down

[image]

**Filtered**
[image]

Comment: @Falcon Pilot, if you're not allowed to use `SUBTOTAL()` you should be able to use `AGGREGATE(9, 5, $B$3:B3) - AGGREGATE(9, 5, $C$3:C3)`.